# How to display search item in Jtable?

Tags: java, sql

I am not able to search a particular item from the database and put it into the Jtable
here is the code i am using:

```
 try{
      String filename="stock.mdb";
      String database="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
      database += filename.trim()+ ";DriverID=22;READONLY=FALSE}";
      conn=DriverManager.getConnection (database, "", "");


      Statement sta= conn.createStatement();
      String str=search.getText();
      String sql="SELECT '"+str+"' FROM stockDB";
      ResultSet rs= sta.executeQuery(sql);
      Table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

      System.out.println("SEARCH UPDATED");

  }catch(Exception e)
  {
      System.out.println(e);
```

}

What is wrong with it?

Comment: search is the the name of text field

Comment: What is your output? What is wrong with it?

Comment: When i am clicking the button it does nothing but when i click it again the table is filled with text i am searching all the colums are gone table header is expr1000

Comment: So you want to return 1 row but instead it is returning all of the rows? Or it is returning nothing?

Comment: I want to search the text and return its corresponding rows and tables

Comment: i tried to use another string which is not in the database the result is same the string i use is displaying all over the table which means the problem is with the code itself.

Comment: So whatever you put in the str variable is filling up your entire table? Why don't you test it on a dummy table you create with only 3 rows.

Comment: Do you see any problem with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you see any problem with the code?

1. variable names should NOT start with an upper case character ("Table" should be "table").
2. Your select statement isn't doing a search. You are selecting a column name. When you do a search you should have a "where" clause that contains the string your are searching for.
3. Use a `PreparedStatement` when creating your SQL statement. It will build the query with the proper delimiters so you don't need to worry about making a syntax error.

Comment: @CodeCamper Done bro.. can you tell me how to close a single Jframe not the whole program?

Comment: @user3551620 you should ask another question and as you type the question see if the answer pops up, if it doesn't then ask it in case future people have the same question.